# Is it possible to Filter an ICollectionView to only show children instead of the whole Hierarchy?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, filter, prism

I've been trying to Filter an ObservableCollection (something similar to a TreeView) to only show the exact hits of the filter and not the whole Hierarchy. And this needs to be done without adding a second ObservableCollection, since that would just make the whole code harder to maintain.

So, for instance, let's say we have the following Hierarchy:

```
Item1
 -Item1-1
 -Item1-2
   --Item1-2-1
      ---Item1-2-1-1
Item2
 -Item2-1
 -Item2-2
```

And I'd like to filter it by "-2". The result I'm expecting is:

```
Item1-2
Item1-2-1
Item1-2-1-1
Item2-2
```

But the result I'm getting is as this:

```
Item1
 -Item1-2
   --Item1-2-1
      ---Item1-2-1-1
Item2
 -Item2-1
```

So no Hierarchy of any kind is shown upon filtering. Is this possible? So far what I've got is the following code for filtering:

```
private ICollectionView _visibleItems;
    public ICollectionView VisibleItems
    {
        get
        {
                return GetVisibleItems(_items);
        }
    }

    private ICollectionView GetVisibleItems( ObservableCollection<TreeSource> ts )
    {
        if (ts != null)
        {
            _visibleItems = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ts);
            _visibleItems.Filter = i => !(( TreeSource )i).IsFilteredOut;

            RaisePropertyChanged("VisibleItems");
        }
        return _visibleItems;
    }

    public string Filter
    {
        get { return _filter; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _filter, value);
            foreach (TreeSource item in _items)
            {
                item.ApplyFilter(_filter);
            }

            VisibleItems.Refresh();
        }
    }

internal void ApplyFilter(string filter)
    {
        IsFilteredOut = Text.IndexOf(filter, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) < 0;

        if (Children == null)
            return;

        foreach (var child in Children)
        {
            child.ApplyFilter(filter);

            //if (!child.IsFilteredOut)
            //{
            //    IsFilteredOut = false;
            //}
        }

        VisibleChildren.Refresh();

    }
```

Comment: Did you try to debug IsFilteredOut property during the filtering? Does it shows right values based on current filter?

Comment: What I have from IsFilteredOut is the following: 

Item1 (true)

 -Item1-1 (true)
 -Item1-2 (false)
   --Item1-2-1 (false)
      ---Item1-2-1-1 (false)
Item2 (true)
 -Item2-1 (true)
 -Item2-2 (false)

So it seems about right to me, but _visibleItems.Filter will cut out all the childs just because the father IsFilteredOut flag is set to true.

If I comment out the if (!child.IsFilteredOut) part, I get the following:

Item1 (false)
 -Item1-2 (false)
   --Item1-2-1 (false)
      ---Item1-2-1-1 (false)
Item2 (false)
 -Item2-1 (true)
 -Item2-2 (false)